# How can I split string to lines with specific width using unix commands? When the input string is infinite?

Tags: perl, unix, sed

I want to convert

```
Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.He...
```

to

```
Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.He
llo.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hell
o.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.
Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.He
...,
```

where the width is 80 characters.

I firstly thought that I can use `sed`. (Let me explain with `5` characters instead of `80` characters to clarify.)

```
echo "longlonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglonglong" | sed 's/\(.\{5\}\)/\1\'$'\n/g'
```

gives

```
longl
onglo
nglon
glong
longl
onglo
nglon
glong
longl
ong
```

as I want. However, I could not use this way when the input string lasts forever.

```
while true; do; echo -n "Hello."; done | sed 's/\(.\{5\}\)/\1\'$'\n/g'
```

The above command does not work. I also tried using `perl`, but in vain. (`perl -pe 's/(.{5})/$1\n/g'`)
So I gave up solving within unix commands and wrote a small programme in C.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int i = 0, ch;
  while ((ch = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF) {
    putchar((char)ch);
    i += 1;
    if (ch == '\n') {
      i = 0;
    }
    if (i >= 80) {
      printf("\n");
      i = 0;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The programme works nice for me. So the question is, how can I split long long (probably infinite) input string into lines using unix commands?

Comment: There is no point in reinventing the wheel: [man fold](http://linux.die.net/man/1/fold)

Comment: Thank you! I did not know the `fold` command.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`fold` can be your friend:

```
$ fold -w 80 file
Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.He
llo.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hell
o.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.
Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.He
...

$ fold -w 20 file
Hello.Hello.Hello.He
llo.Hello.Hello.Hell
o.Hello.Hello.Hello.
Hello.Hello.Hello.He
llo.Hello.Hello.Hell
o.Hello.Hello.Hello.
Hello.Hello.Hello.He
llo.Hello.Hello.Hell
o.Hello.Hello.Hello.
Hello.Hello.Hello.He
llo.Hello.Hello.Hell
o.Hello.Hello.Hello.
Hello.Hello.Hello.He
llo.Hello.Hello.Hell
o.Hello.Hello.Hello.
Hello.Hello.Hello.He
...
```

From `man fold`:

> fold - wrap each input line to fit in specified width
>
> **-w**, --width=WIDTH
>
> use WIDTH columns instead of 80

So in fact `fold file` is the same as `fold -w 80 file`

Comment: Thank you! I did not know the `fold` command. It works well as I want.

Comment: Thanks again for noting that the default value is 80. It's a nice behaviour.

Answer (score 6):

You could use perl one liner,

```
perl -lpe 'BEGIN{ $/ = \80 }' file
```

From [`peldoc perlvar`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html)

> *$/*
>
> The input record separator, newline by default. [..] Setting *$/* to a reference to an integer, scalar containing an integer, or scalar that's convertible to an integer will attempt to read records instead of lines, with the maximum record size being the referenced integer number of characters

Comment: Does it actually work for you? Have you tried the OP test? namely `while true; do echo -n 'Hello.'; done |perl -pe 's|.{1,80}\K|\n|g'`

Comment: Thank you for a solution using `perl`. I upvoted because it actually works as I expected. It looks like a magic for me, as a Perl beginner, though.

Comment: @itchyny added explanation for `$/`

Comment: @AvinashRaj yes, you can avoid this behavior `perl -lpe 'BEGIN{ $/ = \80 } $\ ="" if eof' file` or `perl -nE 'BEGIN{ $/ = \80 } eof() ? print : say' file`

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below perl code also,

```
$ perl -0777pe 's/(.{80})/\1\n/g' file
Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.He
llo.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hell
o.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.
Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.Hello.He
...
```

Answer (score 0):

try option `-u`

> -u   (--unbuffered)
>
> Buffer both input and output as minimally as practical. (This is particularly useful if the input is coming from the likes of ‘tail -f’, and you wish to see the transformed output as soon as possible.)

```
sed -u 's/\(.\{5\}\)/\1\'$'\n/g'
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion. Sorry but it seems that that option is not implemented on my system. It gives `sed: illegal option -- u`.

Comment: which system ? work on my AIX and is part of GNU sed

Comment: sed on Mac is indeed missing this option (from man page i just read). Sorry. The only option in this area is `-l` for a buffered output.