# Word-wrapping an stream of text with perl

Tags: perl

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25604673/632407) folding lines by characters. Here is already an nice [perl answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25604728/632407), based of the `$/` variable.

I was tried make an `Text::Wrap` (core module) solution for word-wrapping, unfortunately without success.

My test generator is:

```
perl -E 'srand(1);for(;;){print join("",map{("a".."z")[rand 26]}1..(3+rand 10))," ";}'
```

The above will generate an stream of words like:

```
lvi aeztjjod ydp udqfa yixpkxsf acwdthqlnilr uvizrdwsjo hygoqon chstr jnoryfpco yfuip qxjgmxiviypz foyqoz zqvrce czwqb hsjzdgxsxlg pozstag mcnwksf lhshrqi ...
```

e.g running it as:

```
perl -E 'srand(1);
for(;;){print join("",map{("a".."z")[rand 26]}1..(3+rand 10))," ";}' | fold -s
```

will get word-wrapped lines like:

```
lvi aeztjjod ydp udqfa yixpkxsf acwdthqlnilr uvizrdwsjo hygoqon chstr jnoryfpco 
yfuip qxjgmxiviypz foyqoz zqvrce czwqb hsjzdgxsxlg pozstag mcnwksf lhshrqi fjy 
hqdeqnph ujulsh jtjcpzbhzw ujnnfom gujgiurptdla dtyoym ooyluqjyxhr nbo wcw
...
```

How to achieve such word-wrapping with perl?

My script is:

```
use 5.014;
use warnings;
use Text::Wrap;

$Text::Wrap::columns=80;

while( sysread(STDIN, my $buff,1024) ) { #using sysread for reading unbuffered data
    print wrap(undef,undef,$buff);
}
```

but this wraps OK only the first 1024 characters, and don't know how to "continue" on the same line to getting result such as from the `fold -s` command.

**EDIT**, just realized than the whole logic reading a block of characters is wrong, because e.g. reading 800 characters (what is multiply of 80) could give a wrong result, when the word starts at 798 and have a length e.g. 10 chars. In this case, the first read will get the first 2 characters, and the subsequent read the remaining characters from the word, but it will be delimited by space...

**EDIT2** ... unless using the trick from the @choroba's answer, separating the last (not full line) with the next incoming buffer.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using `sysread` in chunks of 1024 and not just using normal `readline`?

Comment: @TLP Can't read a "line" because here is only ONE line, and can't slurp it because it is streamed (aka "infinite" long data-stream).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strip the last (possibly shorter) line from the wrapped text, add it to the following portion to be wrapped later:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Text::Wrap qw{ wrap };

# $Text::Wrap::break   = qr/\s/;
$Text::Wrap::columns = 80;

my $firstline = q();
while (sysread STDIN, my $buff, 1041) {
    my $wrapped = wrap(undef, undef, $firstline . $buff);
    $wrapped =~ s/\n(.*)$/\n/;
    my $lastline = $1;
    print $wrapped;
    $firstline = $lastline;
}
```

Note that I kept the default value for `$break` to get the same output as `fold -s`.

Answer (score 0):

@novacik : The simple thing is to change your input record seperator with the required number of characters like `$/ = \80;` or `$/ = \1024;`or give as many number of characters you want to wrap from the input file. You can divide the whole input file into many number of chunks.