# split file with newlines at nearest whitespace chars prior to every 80th char

Tags: bash, sed

I want to insert a newline at the nearest whitespace char just prior to every 80th character in a large text file that reads as a single line of text.

I can think how I could split the file split exactly at every 80th char using something like:

```
sed -ri "s/.\{80\}/&\n/g" file.txt
```

and then go thru and bring each line that begins with a char up to be merge with the previous line if it ends exactly on non-whitespace char and split at the last whitespace char prior to the newline char with something like:

```
sed -ri '/[^ ]$/N;s/^(.*) ([^ ]*)\n/\1\n\2/' file.txt
```

but this seems kind of awkward and almost certainly unnecessary as I am sure there is likely a cleaner way to manage such a task in bash.

Oh yeah, there are lots of single dash hyphens in the file surrounded by space, and so I would want to avoid a split on any space immediately followed by or preceeded by a single dash.

Comment: Please update your question to provide some sample data that resembles your real data. It allows for quick test of the solution.

Comment: It looks pretty similar to [How can I split string to lines with specific width using unix commands? When the input string is infinite?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25604673/how-can-i-split-string-to-lines-with-specific-width-using-unix-commands-when-th/25604803#25604803) --> `fold -w 80 -s file`

Comment: @fedorqui Thats just the first part of the question. There is a second part to it which starts from `and then go thru and bring each line ...` which I am not able to follow clearly.

Comment: @jaypal true. It would be good if the OP can provide some sample input file and desired output.

Comment: What do the single-dash hyphens represent, that you don't want to split on the surrounding spaces?

Comment: I am formatting some traditional xmas songs in which the hyphens represent pauses and so (for me at least) not a place in the text where I want lines to break. Not a big deal now that rici's answers makes it easy peasy to manage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your requirement about hyphens is not exactly clear to me. Normally, text-flowing will break words after a hyphen (if a hyphen is present in the text) and better text formatting systems will automatically hyphenate words using a dictionary and some built-in heuristics. However, the standard Unix tools don't have these features; they just treat hyphens the same as any other character.

If your text has hyphens in it, but they are surrounded by spaces, then you (probably) want to avoid the line break being before the hyphen; I don't see why you wouldn't want it after the hyphen. In either case, if you want to avoid line breaks, you'll need to somehow preprocess the text to avoid the problem. One way would be to replace the spaces which you don't want to be used for line-breaking with a different character, such as a non-breaking space (Unicode character `U+A0`).

For example, you could use a pipeline like this to avoid breaking before a hyphen:

```
sed "s/ \+-/"$'\u00A0'"-/g" file.txt | fmt -w 80
```

or, if you wanted avoid breaking either before or after:

```
sed "s/ \+-/"$'\u00A0'"-/g;s/- \+/-"$'\u00A00'"/g" file.txt | fmt -w 80
```

and, if you wanted to get rid of the non-breaking spaces afterwards:

```
sed "s/ \+-/"$'\u00A0'"-/g;s/- \+/-"$'\u00A00'"/g" file.txt |
fmt -w 80 |
sed $'s/\u00A0/ /g'
```

In all cases, I suggest the use of `fmt` (if available) which will not only reflow and break lines at spaces to try not to exceed a maximum line length; it will also attempt to do so in a way which avoids short lines. See the `-g` option in the manpage, `man fmt`.

If `fmt` is not available, you might want to look into the `python` module [`textwrap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.TextWrapper), which has even more options.

Comment: replacing surrounding spaces around hyphens (I used underscore) and replacing hyphens (I used ampersand) with alternate chars makes perfect sense. And I did not know about the `fmt` command which worked perfect.

Answer (score 4):

If available, I would use `fmt` instead of `sed` to wrap your lines.

```
fmt -w 80 file.txt
```

(Or adjust the line width as necessary.)

Comment: @fedorqui: `fold` only breaks; you need `fmt` to flow. But neither of them solve the requirement about hyphens.

Comment: @rici `fold` has the `-s` option --> "-s, --spaces. break at spaces". It should make it. Anyway, yes, this is just half of the question.

Comment: @fedorqui: I know what `fold` does. It only breaks; you can tell it whether or not to only break on spaces, but it only breaks; it does not reflow.

Comment: I missed the hyphen requirement.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed ':a
s/\(.\{80\}\)\(.\)/\1³\2/
tb
b
:b
s/\(.*\) \([^ ]*\)³/\1³\2/
s/³/\^J/^JP
s/.*\n//
ta' YourFile
```

Just for fun, fmt and other are made for.

- Use of `³` as marker, other char could be used (especialy if present in file)
- No New line added on line of exactly 80 char
- force new line at 80 char if no space found earlier